# HTML element from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{ "quiz": { "q1": { "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?", "options": [ "New York Bulls", "Los Angeles Kings", "Golden State Warriros", "Huston Rocket" ], "answer": "Huston Rocket" }, "q2": { "question": "'Namaste' is a traditional greeting in which Asian language?", "options": [ "Hindi", "Mandarin", "Nepalese", "Thai" ], "answer": "Hindi" }, "q3": { "question": "The Spree river flows through which major European capital city?", "options": [ "Berlin", "Paris", "Rome", "London" ], "answer": "Berlin" }, "q4": { "question": "Which famous artist had both a 'Rose Period' and a 'Blue Period'?", "options": [ "Pablo Picasso", "Vincent van Gogh", "Salvador Dalí", "Edgar Degas" ], "answer": "Pablo Picasso" } } }
```

I have to get elements from it and return html element with it. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
 let promise = fetch('quiz.json').then(function (response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error("Error while reading this file.");
        }

        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
       for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            document.body.innerHTML += '<h2>' + data[i].question + '</h2>'
            document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio">' + data[i].options  
        }            

        console.log(data);

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    });
```

Comment: @peinearydevelopment — That line is never reached because the previous line returns `response,json()`.

Comment: ["didn't work" isn't a useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Are errors reported? Are any of the log statements triggered? What happens if you add more logging?

Comment: Please format your code better. Double spacing every new line makes it hard to read.

Comment: You need to work with the data structure **you actually have**. `data` is an object with one property (`quiz`). There are no arrays anywhere in your data structure.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (let que in data.quiz) {
   document.body.innerHTML += '<h2>' + que.question + '</h2>';
   for (let i = 0; i < que.options.length; i++) {
     document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="radio">' + que.options[i];
   }
}
```

Correct the loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).